# Remove any span with specific class in selected text

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove any  tag with the class "high" in any selected text of a contentEditable div.

No matters if the span node is fully selected or partially selected! Like the example:

[image]

In this example above, note that the span with "adipiscing elit" text is just partially selected! But when user clicks one button "remove highlight", I'm trying to make this `<span>` class vanish! But keep the text (remove only the tag). And if the selection has one or more spans with the class "high", all should be removed!

I'm stuck because I don't know how to get the index of the node, for example. I was able to identify if there is a span with that class in the selection. But how to do this removal?

Here is what I have:

```
<div contentEditable='true' spellcheck='false'>
Lorem ipsum <a href='eer.htm'>dolor sit amet</a>, consectetur <span class='high'>adipiscing elit</span>. Ut lacinia eros ut orci pellentesque vulputate. Mauris sodales odio.
</div>
<br />
<button id='remove'>Remove Highlight</button>
```

JS:

```
remove.onclick = e => remove();

function nextNode(node) {
    if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
        return node.firstChild;
    } else {
        while (node && !node.nextSibling) {
            node = node.parentNode;
        }
        if (!node) {
            return null;
        }
        return node.nextSibling;
    }
}

function getRangeSelectedNodes(range) {
    var node = range.startContainer;
    var endNode = range.endContainer;
    if (node == endNode) {
        return [node];
    }
    var rangeNodes = [];
    while (node && node != endNode) {
        rangeNodes.push( node = nextNode(node) );
    }
    node = range.startContainer;
    while (node && node != range.commonAncestorContainer) {
        rangeNodes.unshift(node);
        node = node.parentNode;
    }
    return rangeNodes;
}

function getSelectedNodes() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        if (!sel.isCollapsed) {
            return getRangeSelectedNodes(sel.getRangeAt(0));
        }
    }
    return [];
}

function remove() {
    var nds = getSelectedNodes();
    var i;
    for(i=0; i<=nds.length;i++) {
        if(nds[i] instanceof HTMLSpanElement) {
            if(nds[i].classList == 'high') {
                var spanText = nds[i].textContent;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```js
remove.onclick = e => remove();
    
    function nextNode(node) {
        if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
            return node.firstChild;
        } else {
            while (node && !node.nextSibling) {
                node = node.parentNode;
            }
            if (!node) {
                return null;
            }
            return node.nextSibling;
        }
    }
    
    function getRangeSelectedNodes(range) {
        var node = range.startContainer;
        var endNode = range.endContainer;
        if (node == endNode) {
            return [node];
        }
        var rangeNodes = [];
        while (node && node != endNode) {
            rangeNodes.push( node = nextNode(node) );
        }
        node = range.startContainer;
        while (node && node != range.commonAncestorContainer) {
            rangeNodes.unshift(node);
            node = node.parentNode;
        }
        return rangeNodes;
    }
    
    function getSelectedNodes() {
        if (window.getSelection) {
            var sel = window.getSelection();
            if (!sel.isCollapsed) {
                return getRangeSelectedNodes(sel.getRangeAt(0));
            }
        }
        return [];
    }
    
    function remove() {
        var nds = getSelectedNodes();
        var i;
        for(i=0; i<=nds.length;i++) {
            if(nds[i] instanceof HTMLSpanElement) {
                if(nds[i].classList == 'high') {
                    var spanText = nds[i].textContent;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

```css
.high { background:yellow; }
```

```html
    <div contentEditable='true' spellcheck='false'>
    Lorem ipsum <a href='eer.htm'>dolor sit amet</a>, consectetur <span class='high'>adipiscing elit</span>. Ut lacinia eros ut orci pellentesque vulputate. Mauris sodales odio.
    </div>
    <br />
    <button id='remove'>Remove Highlight</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.classList.contains` and `.classList.remove`. See [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

```js
document.getElementById("remove").onclick = e => remove();
    
    function nextNode(node) {
        if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
            return node.firstChild;
        } else {
            while (node && !node.nextSibling) {
                node = node.parentNode;
            }
            if (!node) {
                return null;
            }
            return node.nextSibling;
        }
    }
    
    function getRangeSelectedNodes(range) {
        var node = range.startContainer;
        var endNode = range.endContainer;
        if (node == endNode) {
            return [node];
        }
        var rangeNodes = [];
        while (node && node != endNode) {
            rangeNodes.push( node = nextNode(node) );
        }
        node = range.startContainer;
        while (node && node != range.commonAncestorContainer) {
            rangeNodes.unshift(node);
            node = node.parentNode;
        }
        return rangeNodes;
    }
    
    function getSelectedNodes() {
        if (window.getSelection) {
            var sel = window.getSelection();
            if (!sel.isCollapsed) {
                return getRangeSelectedNodes(sel.getRangeAt(0));
            }
        }
        return [];
    }
    
    function remove() {
        var nds = getSelectedNodes();
        var i;
        for(i=0; i<=nds.length;i++) {
            if(nds[i] instanceof HTMLSpanElement) {
                if(nds[i].classList.contains('high')) {
                        nds[i].classList.remove('high');
                    var spanText = nds[i].textContent;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

```css
.high { background:yellow; }
```

```html
    <div contentEditable='true' spellcheck='false'>
    Lorem ipsum <a href='eer.htm'>dolor sit amet</a>, consectetur <span class='high'>adipiscing elit</span>. Ut lacinia eros ut orci pellentesque vulputate. Mauris sodales odio.
    </div>
    <br />
    <button id='remove'>Remove Highlight</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for this,, it would be nise if it removes the span with empty class,,, but thanks,, I will try to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

You code is long but, your main issue is this right.
You can't remove the highlighted text.

Your `Remove Highlight` button cant execute your `remove()` function. you should at least properly target it first. like below.

`document.querySelector('#remove').onclick = e => remove();`

and add

`document.querySelector('.high').remove();`

to remove the text with hightlight

```
document.querySelector('#remove').onclick = e => remove();
function remove() {

    var nds = getSelectedNodes();
    var i;
    for(i=0; i<=nds.length;i++) {
        if(nds[i] instanceof HTMLSpanElement) {
            if(nds[i].classList == 'high') {
                var spanText = nds[i].textContent;
            }
        }
    }
 document.querySelector('.high').remove();
}
```

```js
    
    function nextNode(node) {
        if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
            return node.firstChild;
        } else {
            while (node && !node.nextSibling) {
                node = node.parentNode;
            }
            if (!node) {
                return null;
            }
            return node.nextSibling;
        }
    }
    
    function getRangeSelectedNodes(range) {
        var node = range.startContainer;
        var endNode = range.endContainer;
        if (node == endNode) {
            return [node];
        }
        var rangeNodes = [];
        while (node && node != endNode) {
            rangeNodes.push( node = nextNode(node) );
        }
        node = range.startContainer;
        while (node && node != range.commonAncestorContainer) {
            rangeNodes.unshift(node);
            node = node.parentNode;
        }
        return rangeNodes;
    }
    
    function getSelectedNodes() {
        if (window.getSelection) {
            var sel = window.getSelection();
            if (!sel.isCollapsed) {
                return getRangeSelectedNodes(sel.getRangeAt(0));
            }
        }
        return [];
    }
    
document.querySelector('#remove').onclick = e => remove();
    function remove() {

        var nds = getSelectedNodes();
        var i;
        for(i=0; i<=nds.length;i++) {
            if(nds[i] instanceof HTMLSpanElement) {
                if(nds[i].classList == 'high') {
                    var spanText = nds[i].textContent;
                }
            }
        }
     document.querySelector('.high').remove();
    }
```

```css
.high { background:yellow; }
```

```html
<div contentEditable='true' spellcheck='false'>
    Lorem ipsum <a href='eer.htm'>dolor sit amet</a>, consectetur <span class='high'>adipiscing elit</span>. Ut lacinia eros ut orci pellentesque vulputate. Mauris sodales odio.
    </div>
    <br />
    <button id='remove'>Remove Highlight</button>
```